# add vertical scrollbar to flex tooltip

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

I want to add scrollbar to the flex tootip. So i created custom tool tip. Below is the code snippet. Problem i am facing is that as soon as i move the mouse on the custom component tooltip, the custom component tooltip disppear. i have alse set the ToolTipManager.hideDelay = Infinity. I want to use the scrollbar of the cutom tool tip.
I do not want the custom tool top to hide till i move the mouse outside the custom tool tip component.Currently it hide itself once i move the mouse outside the label. How to control the destroy of tool tip.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
     width="100%" 
     height="100%"
     implements="mx.core.IToolTip">

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        private var _bodyText:String = "";

        [Bindable]
        public function get bodyText():String
        {
            return _bodyText;
        }

        public function set bodyText(value:String):void
        {
            _bodyText = value;
            text = value;
        }


        private var _text:String;

        public function get text():String
        {
            return _text;
        }

        public function set text(value:String):void
        {
            _text = value;
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>

    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="200">
         <s:RichEditableText text="{bodyText}" width="100%" height="100%" color="red"/>   
    </s:Scroller>

</s:Group>
```

and i add this cutom tooltip on mx:label component on toolTipCreate event.

```
protected function label1_toolTipCreateHandler(event:ToolTipEvent):void
{

ScrollableToolTip ptt = new ScrollableToolTip();
ptt.bodyText = data.notes;
ptt.height = 300;
ptt.width = 100;
event.toolTip = ptt;
}
```

Any pointers..

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the flex tooltip, you may want to add a popup on mouse roll over and deal with it that way, ofcoz you have to deal with the positioning of the popup later on, but I think this will give you a lot of flexibility later on.